# A rolling chart of data with ZedGraph, where the data is stored in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, zedgraph

I have a large amount of data in sql server (too much to load into memory all at once in my pc). I was planning to use paging in sql server to retrieve predefined blocks of data. What im wondering is, is it possible to setup Zedgraph such that once a user scrolls to the right (newest data), a new chunk of data is retrieved from the sql server, displayed and the oldest chunk of data is removed from the charts memory?

If this isnt possible, is there a free alternative to ZedGraph which would be able to do the following?

Thanks